# My dispatch function isn't triggering my useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

```js
useEffect(
    function fetchNotes() {
        fetch('/notes', {method: 'GET'})
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                data.sort((a, b) => a.title.localeCompare(b.title));
                if(!isArchived) {
                    const activeNotes = data.filter(n => !n.archived);
                    const uniqueTags = [...new Set(activeNotes.flatMap(note => note.tags))];
                    setTagFilter(uniqueTags);
                    dispatch({type: 'CHOOSE', arr: activeNotes});
                } else {
                    const archivedNotes = data.filter(n => n.archived);
                    const uniqueTags = [...new Set(archivedNotes.flatMap(note => note.tags))];
                    setTagFilter(uniqueTags);
                    dispatch({type: 'CHOOSE', arr: archivedNotes});
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching notes:', error);
            });
    }, [dispatch, isArchived ]
);
```

```js
const reducer = (state, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD':
            return [...state, action.newNote];
        case 'DELETE':
            return state.filter(note => note.id !== action.id);
        case 'CHOOSE': 
            return action.arr
        case 'CHANGE TAGS':
            return state.map(note => {
                if(note.id === action.id) {
                    return {...note, tags: action.newTags}
                } else {
                    return note
                }
            })
        case 'ARCHIVE':
            return state.map(note => (note.id === action.id ? { ...note, archived: action.archived } : note));
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default reducer`
```

In my dependencies array, I've included my dispatch function from the reducer, however after calling dispatch useEffect does not trigger.

Full code is in this repo: https://github.com/RonanFilloy/Keep-clone

Comment: where did you call the function? call the function inside the useEffect hook to trigger the function.

Comment: `useEffect` is not listening for function calls. `useEffect` checks if variables changed